# How to save random variables in the same spot?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a google sheet that makes a random character, but every time I edit it the sheet changes. I am trying to make it so the character sheet won't change when you hit the button. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z7cSTIxBNf6BV9BIZFvWn_VMqa8Gh8ohebKAKlKNXZY/edit?usp=sharing

I know that the random variable change every time because they are like the now(). However, I have code in the cells that I need to change to the number that it shows, so the cells won't change after I hit save character.

```
// custom menu function
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Save Character','saveCharacter')
      .addToUi();
}

// function to save character
function saveCharacter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var stats = sheets.getRange("F9:F14");
  sheets.getRange("F9:F14").setValue(stats);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it now. Thanks to anyone that tried helping me I found a long and round about way of saving each cell.

```
// custom menu function
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Save A Character','saveaCharacter')
      .addToUi();
}

// function to save character
function saveaCharacter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //this establishes the sheets
  var front = ss.getSheets()[1];
  //this establishes the character front page
  var race = front.getRange("T1").getValues();
  var gender = front.getRange("AB1").getValues();
  var diety = front.getRange("AQ1").getValues();
  var al = front.getRange("AH1").getValues();
  var background = front.getRange("AF3").getValues();
  var class = front.getRange("Z10").getValues();
  var hp = front.getRange("AO10").getValues();
  var armor = front.getRange("AS20").getValues();
  var subclass = front.getRange("AS51").getValues();
  var w1 = front.getRange("V29").getValues();
  var w2 = front.getRange("V30").getValues();
  var w3 = front.getRange("V31").getValues();
  var w4 = front.getRange("V32").getValues();
  var w5 = front.getRange("V33").getValues();
  var w6 = front.getRange("V34").getValues();
  var l1 = front.getRange("B47").getValues();
  var l2 = front.getRange("B48").getValues();
  var l3 = front.getRange("B49").getValues();
  var l4 = front.getRange("B50").getValues();
  var l5 = front.getRange("B51").getValues();
  var l6 = front.getRange("B52").getValues();
  var str = front.getRange("F9").getValues();
  var dex = front.getRange("F10").getValues();
  var con = front.getRange("F11").getValues();
  var int = front.getRange("F12").getValues();
  var wis = front.getRange("F13").getValues();
  var cha = front.getRange("F14").getValues();
  //this lists the character
  front.getRange("AB1").setValue(gender);
  front.getRange("AQ1").setValue(diety);
  front.getRange("AH1").setValue(al);
  front.getRange("Z10").setValue(class);
  front.getRange("AO10").setValue(hp);
  front.getRange("AS20").setValue(armor);
  front.getRange("AF3").setValue(background);
  front.getRange("T1").setValue(race);
  front.getRange("AS51").setValue(subclass);
  front.getRange("V29").setValue(w1);
  front.getRange("V30").setValue(w2);
  front.getRange("V31").setValue(w3);
  front.getRange("V32").setValue(w4);
  front.getRange("V33").setValue(w5);
  front.getRange("V34").setValue(w6);
  front.getRange("B47").setValue(l1);
  front.getRange("B48").setValue(l2);
  front.getRange("B49").setValue(l3);
  front.getRange("B50").setValue(l4);
  front.getRange("B51").setValue(l5);
  front.getRange("B52").setValue(l6);
  front.getRange("F9").setValue(str);
  front.getRange("F10").setValue(dex);
  front.getRange("F11").setValue(con);
  front.getRange("F12").setValue(int);
  front.getRange("F13").setValue(wis);
  front.getRange("F14").setValue(cha);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tristian, your question doesn't make any sense. You created a menu item named "Save Character" and when it's pressed it will call the 'saveCharacter' function. Then you get the ActiveSpreadsheet and the 0th sheet of that spreadsheet.  Now you have to create a random number and save it to the cell you want to save it to. To save it you use the getRange() method of the Sheet Class and then the setValue() method to set the value in that range or cell. I'm not sure how you're generating the random number or what you want to do with the ones you're saving so you may need to do some other things to get everything arranged the way you want them arranged.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: thank you for trying to help I am generating the random cell on the sheet and I need to save it as the cell that's generating it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are requesting a custom cell function.  I think this will work for you.  In the future let us know when you're talking about cell functions.  Normally, we get questions about Google Apps Script functions that are not intended to be used as cell functions.  Actually if you had capitalized the entire name that would have triggered many of us to think it was a cell function as well.

```
function SAVECHARACTER(r) {
  var chars='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345678!@#$%^&*()_-=+[]{}|\.,<>?/:;~'; 
  return chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*chars.length));
}
```

- [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: I am not trying to make a custom cell function. I have code in some cells that randomizes what they are. I am trying to make it so I can hit the Save Character Button and it will turn all the cells into what they show instead of the code.

Comment: What do you mean `I have code in some cells`? Can you give me an example?